# why I received the error "llvm-dis: Invalid bitcode signature"

Tags: clang, llvm

```
clang hello_world.c -S -emit-llvm -o hello_world.bc
llvm-dis hello_world.bc
```

I would like to generate human readable ll file using llvm-dis, but I received the erorr

llvm-dis: Invalid bitcode signature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the `-S` option, `clang` already produces human-readable LLVM assembly. So your .bc file does not actually contain bitcode, which is why llvm-dis can't read it.